# PHP - Get File Name of Running Script from Windows Processes?

Tags: powershell, process, cmd, windows-server-2008

I have three PHP processes running.  One of the processes is running `script_one.php` and the other two are running `script_two.php`.  When I use `Get-Process` in command line, all three proceses list "php" as the process name.

Is there anyway to differentiate the different scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -Filter "Name = 'php.exe'" |
 Where {$_.CommandLine -match 'my_script\.php'}
```

Comment: I get an `Invalid query "select * from win32_process where ProcessName = 'php.exe'"` error

Comment: What PS version are you running?

Comment: Was able to get it to work after taking out `ProcessID`.  If I wanted to add a second filter that looked for `my_script.php` within the `CommandLine`, how would I do so?